# Safari open a web page from cache offline

Tags: safari, history

I want to open a web page which i could see in safari's history offline. At-least i want to get the html contents out of it.

It would be of great help if anyone could help me do it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the page on the internet right now? If so then I suggest browsing to the page and issuing a **File, Save** command:

[image: safari browser: file, save]

If you need to extract the page from the cache while you are offline, try

`C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Apple Computer\Safari`

it is in a `cache.db` file which is apparently a [SQlite database](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Info on how to pick apart this file is at

http://forensicsfromthesausagefactory.blogspot.com/2010/06/safari-browser-cache-examination-of.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The cache.db is there only for past 2 days. I want to retrieve data from the cache 20 days back. I take backup of my system using time machine backup, but sadly even time machine backup excludes the safari cache directory. Is there any way?

Comment: Do safari create save-points where we can rollback to?